# Select * from all tables with the same prefix

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating tables for every year of specific data. How can I create mysql query to browse all the tables with specific prefix and show the results like from one table? I would like to make an elegant query, not to use arrays.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Are you sure that your database structure is sound? Why not store everything in the same table and avoid building a query the complex way?

Comment: With proper indexes (and if mysql allows partitioning, not sure) you should not need to seperate out tables by years

Comment: For MyISAM tables you may simply create ENGINE=MERGE under-table. For another engines create stored procedure which will get tablenames from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, build and execute dynamic SELECT with all tables UNIONed.

Comment: Thanks! The idea of creating each table for each year is to avoid making unlimited table. Every year has approx. 3000 entries and listing one year after 12 years would take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas which I have is to create a table storing all the years and using the year as a foreign key you can access the tables of different years.

Comment: Finally I will go with the array of years with join. Other methods seem too complex for me. Thank you very much for your time!